# subview was layout from a thread other than the main thread

Tags: ios

Bug info as following:
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xf28fbd0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

```
1   _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb

2   WebThreadLock

3   -[UIWebTiledView layoutSubviews]

4   -[UIWebDocumentView layoutSubviews]

5   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]

6   -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]

7   -[CALayer layoutSublayers]

8   CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)

9   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)

10  CA::Transaction::commit()

11  CA::Transaction::pop()

12  +[CATransaction commit]

13  FigLayerSynchronizerSynchronizeToMoment

14  itemremote_TimebaseSynchronizationUpdate

15  FigPlayerRemoteCallbacksServer_TimebaseSynchronizationUpdate

16  _XTimebaseSynchronizationUpdate

17  figmoviecallbacks_server

18  fpr_ClientPortCallBack

19  FigExpressNotificationThread

20  figThreadMain

21  _pthread_start

22  thread_start
```

**I know it was caused by updating UI in the thread other than the main thread.But I don't know why it was updated not in the main thread**

Following is the description:
    It was just similiar to the application BaoFengYingYin. It supported autoplay，minimize playing UI，close Playing UI. When I clicked one picture in picWall,it jumped to a uiviewcontroller **A** ，and played audio file，show the audio file content and update the progress of progressview.

**A** was composed by a custom view and a movieplaycontroller variable.

The custom UIView was composed by textview（which show the audio file content）,progressView ， picture，minimize button ，close button.

As it should continue playing the current audio when  I clicked the minimize button ，and when the audio was playing ，I should update the progress of the progressbar in my custom UIView，so I defined the movieplaycontroller variable and custom view as global variable.

The movieplaycontroller variable was initialized in the appdelegate file，But the custom view was initialized in **A**.

When I clicked minimized button and closed button,I will disappear A,and release the custom view at the same time.

**The above is my function need and my implementation. When it enter **A***,I didn't created new thread,so I thought the custom view would not be updated by a thread not in the main.But it would crash when I repeatedly clicked different audio to play.It always happened when I repeated several times and not disciplinarian.
    It would happen on the iPhone4，I did not see it happen on iPhone4s，iphone 5.I had not iPhone 3gs，so I didnot know if it would happened too.*

```
Now I modify my code to add the custom view by the function  ”performSelectorOnMainThread“ in A's init function.It seemed solved.
```

I published this question，beacuse I want know the reason caused my custom view updating from a thread other than the main thread.
   If someone know,please tell me！Thanks

Comment: Add exception breakpoint to your project catch the place where exception is arising and add that code to your question so that we could identify the problem.

Comment: I‘ll try it again.sometimes I set breakpoints，but there was only system kernel crash info